# How to set background color based on YAML front matter (Jekyll)

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I want to be able to set the background color of a post based on a color defined in the YAML front matter.

This theme does it: [Single Paged](http://t413.com/SinglePaged/) ([github here](https://github.com/t413/SinglePaged))

But I cannot understand how it's being done. This code within the CSS file is what's making it happen:

```
{% for c in site.colors %}
.border-{{c[0]}} { border-color: {{ c[1] }} !important; }
.text-{{c[0]}}   { color: {{ c[1] }}; }
.text-{{c[0]}} a { color: {{ c[1] }}; }
.bg-{{c[0]}}     { background-color: {{ c[1] }} !important; }
{% endfor %}

/* ----- per-post colors! ----- */
{% for node in site.posts %}
  {% capture id %}{{ node.id | remove:'/' | downcase }}{% endcapture %}
  {% capture bg %}{% if site.colors[node.bg] %}{{ site.colors[node.bg] }}{% else %}{{ node.bg }}{% endif %}{% endcapture %}
  {% capture fg %}{% if site.colors[node.color] %}{{ site.colors[node.color] }}{% else %}{{ node.color }}{% endif %}{% endcapture %}
  nav .p-{{id}} { border-color: {{ bg }}; }
  #{{id}} { background-color: {{ bg }} !important; color: {{ fg }}; }
  #{{id}} a { color: {{ fg }}; }
  #{{id}} .sectiondivider { color: {{ bg }}; }
{% endfor %}
```

Is this Liquid within the CSS? Can someone walk me through the code? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the `_config.yml` [file](https://github.com/t413/SinglePaged/blob/gh-pages/_config.yml) for that Jekyll theme:

```
### template colors, used site-wide via css ###
colors:
  black:     '#111111'
  white:     '#f8f8f8'
  blue:      '#49a7e9'
  green:     '#9bcf2f'
  purple:    '#c869bf'
  orange:    '#fab125'
  turquoise: '#0fbfcf'
```

We can see that `colors` is an array of key-values.

**Yes, this is Liquid in CSS.**

(Remember that one can have Liquid's templating engine process any file in Jekyll by adding YAML frontmatter, which is three dashes, [Enter key], and another three dashes. Without the front matter the file is ignored by the Liquid engine)

**Based on the CSS code snippet you've managed to narrow down:**

```
{% for c in site.colors %}
.border-{{c[0]}} { border-color: {{ c[1] }} !important; }
.text-{{c[0]}}   { color: {{ c[1] }}; }
.text-{{c[0]}} a { color: {{ c[1] }}; }
.bg-{{c[0]}}     { background-color: {{ c[1] }} !important; }
{% endfor %}
```

**This is a for-loop that will iterate through all the Key-values in `colors` array.**

An example output for this would be the CSS rule for `black` - `#111111`:

```
.border-black { border-color:  #111111 !important; }
.text-black   { color: #111111; }
.text-black a { color:#111111; }
.bg-black     { background-color: {{ c[1] }} !important; }
```

Since `c` is a variable for each color in the `colors` array, `c[0]` refers to the 'key' which is black, white, blue etc and `c[1]` refers to the 'value' which is the RGB codes respectively. You can also do a `c[3]` if you had another semicolon followed by a value if need be.

*This is repeated for **all** the other colors.*

#### Now for the second snippet of code:

```
/* ----- per-post colors! ----- */
{% for node in site.posts %}
  {% capture id %}{{ node.id | remove:'/' | downcase }}{% endcapture %}
  {% capture bg %}{% if site.colors[node.bg] %}{{ site.colors[node.bg] }}{% else %}{{ node.bg }}{% endif %}{% endcapture %}
  {% capture fg %}{% if site.colors[node.color] %}{{ site.colors[node.color] }}{% else %}{{ node.color }}{% endif %}{% endcapture %}
  nav .p-{{id}} { border-color: {{ bg }}; }
  #{{id}} { background-color: {{ bg }} !important; color: {{ fg }}; }
  #{{id}} a { color: {{ fg }}; }
  #{{id}} .sectiondivider { color: {{ bg }}; }
{% endfor %}
```

**It's another for-loop that iterates through all the posts in `_posts`.**

All the capture tags you see are liquid syntax to get variables. Using [this file](https://github.com/t413/SinglePaged/blob/gh-pages/_posts/2000-01-01-intro.md) as an example:

Notice how the frontmatter is as such:

```
---
title: "home"
bg: white
color: black
style: center
---
```

The variables are captured and put into `bg`, `fg` respectively. `id` is taken from a `posts.id` (I believe this is a special variable in Jekyll), after which the variables are just inserted into where the variables are placed.

The reason it is wrapped inside `capture` and `if` statements are to handle cases where posts do not have bg,fg defined (such as when a programmer forgets to define or if they want a custom color, and avoid broken CSS).

**For all intents and purposes**, just add colors into the `_config.yml` file using the same format of color and then RGB value, and add custom `bg`, `fg` values in each post if you desire. The template will generate all the necessary CSS styles for you.

Comment: That was incredibly helpful! Thank you! 
*Edited to ask: Does [this](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2573) mean that I have to use pure CSS and not SASS for making this work?

Comment: @LiaBogoev glad to help! Well as the way it looks currently yes you'll have to use pure CSS, unless the author has made a SASS version of the stylesheet (which eyeballing the repo doesn't seem to be the case), or you would have to port it over yourself. Also, if this helped please mark it as answered, welcome to StackOverflow!